# i need a way my bot can respond with a random response like and 8ball command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Preferably through a const such as `const responses = ["response1", "response2", response3"] using` discord.js v12.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Creating an array with responses.
const Responses = ["Response1", "Response2", "Response3", "Response4"];

// Picking a random response and logging it.
console.log(Responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * Responses.length)]);
```